# Is it a good idea to put desiccant packs in the freezer?

Tags: food-safety, freezing, drying

Is it a good idea to put desiccant packs, like those you get shipped with electronics, into a working freezer to help prevent it from frosting up inside?

I open our freezer quite often, and the humid air getting closed in there seems to be causing it to frost up quite quickly. I know the contents of those packs are toxic — so that’s a worry — but if they’re sealed, they should be OK, right? I presume for a volume the size of a freezer, you’d need a few and have to replace them regularly...

Comment: If your freezer is frosting up, the first troubleshooting step is to examine the seals. It's unlikely that any residential freezer is accessed enough to make a difference, but a poor seal can constantly let in a small stream of air, and that matters.

Comment: If they're SEALED, they won't do what you want them to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would need a tremendous amount of desiccant to make any significant temporary impact on ice build-up in a freezer. The only major drawback of ice build-up is that it takes up space in the freezer… and the desiccant would take up more space.

BTW, the normal material used as a desiccant is silica gel, which is non-toxic.

Comment: Ice build-up can reduce cooling efficiency, and can play havoc with auto-defrost cycles (when those don't prevent icing).  Silica gel is a choking hazard and can cause internal blockages; the uncommon coloured types can be toxic.  But it can hold very little moisture, so this answer is correct, it wouldn't be much use

Comment: Even worse, I'd be wary of that stuff freezing, expanding, bursting and shedding silica dust all over the food :)